# List iteration issue in Python

Tags: python

I am working with Google Python class exercises where I am getting this issue -

```
def front_x(words):
  # +++your code here+++
  list = []
  for i,s in enumerate(words):
    print i,s
    if s[0] == 'x':
        list.append(words.pop(i))
  return list

print front_x(['bbb','ccc','axx','xzz','xaa'])
```

my loop is only iterating from 0 to 3, so print i,s is giving me values till 'xzz'.Please point where I am wrong.

Comment: new here, want to know how to do that?

Comment: Check [this portion of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Each answer to question you've asked has a "tick" below the vote counter. When you click it, you basically say "This answer was correct from my POV".

Comment: Thanks, Got it, I will start doing that.

Comment: @Varun:  You can also go back to previous questions and click off on the correct answers.  It won't take very long, and it will help out the people who helped you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't modify something as you're iterating over it. `words.pop(i)` modifies `words`, which you're iterating over via `enumerate()`.

I'd suggest looking at [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for accomplishing your apparent goal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably shouldn't words.pop(). The word you want is most likely in s - add that to the list instead.

Also, note that naming a list "list", will more or less erase the "list" builtin type from your local scope.  It's not a make or break kind of deal, but it's something pylint would warn about.